# select by default previous date with jquery calendar

Tags: javascript

I have datepicker codes below to display me calendar, the current date is selected by default, i would like to select the previous date by default instead (the day before today). I have tried but i failed anybody can help me please?

```
$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved my issue this way

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
    $("#datepicker").click(function() {     
        date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate" , date);               
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", -1)
```

More info: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: Unfortunately when i use your codes it does not display anything i did consult the api already, i failed...